# django rest framework: How to validate a rule in serializers using a related field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have these models:

**product.py**

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    product_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    product_multiple = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**order_item.py**

```py
class OrderItem(models.Model)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items', null=True, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    quantity = models.BigIntegerField(default=1)
    profitability = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to validate in `serializers.py` if the `order_item.quantity % product_multiple != 0`

**serializers.py**

```py
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = ('id', 'order', 'product', 'price',
                  'quantity', 'profitability')

    def validate_quantity(self, value):
        data = self.get_initial()
        quantity = data.get("quantity")

        # This is where the `product.product_multiple` value is needed
        if int(quantity) % product.product_multiple != 0:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Quantity is not multiple")

        return value
```

How can I get the actual `product_multiple` inside the validate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are doing a validation that involves multiple fields, you should use the **validate** method as follows:

```
def validate(self, data):
    quantity = data.get('quantity')
    product = data.get('product')

    if int(quantity) % product.product_multiple != 0:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Quantity is not multiple")
    return data
```

Comment: Thanks friend, this solved the problem for me!! just one change: the function return data.